# Delete Azure table from storage programatically c# but not manually

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Is there a way we do not allow users to delete tables manually by connecting to azure table storage instead allow the c# code to delete it programmatically. This will restrict users accessing the shared table storage from deleting tables.

Comment: A persons security is the same no matter whether its done manually or programatically. You'd need to revoke the users rights to delete, then in your program you'd need to take on a different users credentials.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you. How to revoke users rights from deleting the table?

Comment: According to this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/2724240-azure-table-storage-permissions-to-prevent-deletio you can only revoke table by generating a SAS key with specific rights. I couldn't see anything about denying table delete for role based permission. How do the users currently access the data manually - through their O365 logins?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, azure doesn't have the feature which could enable delete Azure table from storage programatically c# but not manually.

In my opinion, you could share the storage SAS token instead of the storage key.

By using the storage SAS token, we could decide which user have the permission to read ,modify or delete the table record as Nick.McDermaid says(Give the right permission token to right user).

More details about how to generate the SAS token with permission, you could refer to this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#examples-of-sas-uris).